# Get a sub array from multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, extract, sub-array, array-key

I want to get a value form a multidimensional array using `PHP`. I pass the key to the function and if the key contains the value (i.e. without any array value), it will return that. But if that key contains an array value, it will return the whole sub array.

I am adding a sample array for that.

```
<?php

// prepare a list of array for category, subcategory etc...

$category = array(
'Account' => array(
    'Show Balance' => array(
        'Recharge' => 2300,
        'Success' => 12000,
        'Failure' => 25000,
    ),
    'Balance History' => 'your balance is very low for last 2 years',
    'Mini Statement' => 'This is your mini statement. You can have a look of your transaction details',
    'Last Transaction' => 25000
), 
'Deposit' => array(
    'Deposit Limit' => 40000,
    'Make Deposit' => 'Please go to the nearest branch ans deposit the money.',
    'Last Deposit' => 12000
), 
'FAQ' => array(
    'How To Open An Account' => 'Go to your nearest branch fill up a form, submit it to the branch manger with required supporting documents.',
    'How To Withdraw Money' => 'Go to any ATM center swipe the card enter pin and get your money.',
    'How To Add Money' => 'You need to go to your nearest branch and deposit money over there.'
), 
'Loan' => array(
    'Home Loan' => 'This is home loan related answer',
    'Personal Loan' => 'This is personal loan related answer',
    'Car Loan' => 'This is car loan related answer',
    'Bike Loan' => 'This is bike loan related answer'
) ,
'Test',

);
```

Now if i pass my array $category and 'Recharge' as a parameter to any `PHP` function it should return me 2300 as a result.
Now if i pass my array $category and 'Show Balance' as a parameter to any `PHP`function it should return me

```
array(
        'Recharge' => 2300,
        'Success' => 12000,
        'Failure' => 25000,
    )
```

as a result.

Searched a lot on google but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: What do you mean by _"any function"_ in _"if i pass my array $category and 'Recharge' as a parameter to any php function"_? That doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Add that PHP function code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a recursive function for this. do `foreach` and check array key with passed key, if matched return array. if not matched and check array value if it is an array with `is_array()`, if yes, call function again, else return value

```
function getData($categoryArray, $key){
    foreach($categoryArray as $k => $value){ 
        if($k==$key) return $value; 
        if(is_array($value)){ 
            $find = getData($value, $key);
            if($find){
                return $find;
            } 
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$result1 = getData($category, 'Show Balance');
var_dump($result1);
$result = getData($category, 'Recharge');
var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kEOZI)

Answer (score 4):

Try this function, recursive way:

```
function get_key_val($arrs, $k) {
    foreach( $arrs as $key=>$val ) {
        if( $key === $k ) {
            return $val;
        }
        else {
            if( is_array( $val ) ) {
                $ret = get_key_val( $val, $k );

                if( $ret !== NULL) {
                    return $ret;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

echo get_key_val( $category, "Recharge" ); // outputs 2300
```

This can go through every element of the passed array, using **foreach** and **recursion**, until the index is found, and returns the index' value (array or not).

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation of the code. What does it do? Why should the OP try it?

Answer (score 1):

To get Show balance try this:

```
print_r($category['Account']['Show Balance']);
```

To get Recharge try this:

```
print_r($category['Account']['Show Balance']['Recharge']);
```

I just tested the code to make sure it works, It works perfectly.

--Edit--

```
foreach ($category as $cat) {
  print_r($cat['Account']['Recharge']);
  print_r($category['Account']['Show Balance']);
}
```

Comment: Actually i cant write the code in this way to get its value. Because i don't know the key level. That means the key may be at first or second or nth level. So i just need to pass the key and then only i have to get the answer.